# Stuck Transaction: Receiving USDT from Binance Smart Chain to Coinbase Ethereum Address

Tags: wallets, etherscan, network, coinbase, mainnet

I hope you can assist me with a transaction issue I'm currently facing. I received USDT to my Coinbase Ethereum address from Binance Smart Chain, but the transaction is on hold, and I am unable to receive my USDT.

Here's a brief overview of my situation:

**Problem:** The USDT transaction from Binance Smart Chain to my Coinbase Ethereum address is stuck.

**BNB Gas Fee:** Upon checking with Coinbase, I realized that I needed BNB (Binance Coin) to complete the transaction. To address this, I added $2 worth of BNB to my Coinbase wallet.

**No Progress:** Despite adding BNB, the transaction remains on hold, and I haven't received my USDT.

**Transaction Status:** I tried looking up the transaction on the Binance Smart Chain explorer and [etherscan.io](https://etherscan.io/address/0xa56bD889A577AA4987c21396BCB8e1daa311320D), but I couldn't find any conclusive information about the cause of the hold-up.

**Seeking Help:** I am reaching out to this community for guidance on how to resolve the stuck transaction and receive my USDT.

I've tried to take all necessary steps, but I'm still facing this problem. I'm eager to learn if there's anything else I can do to rectify the situation and complete the transaction successfully.

If anyone has encountered a similar issue or has expertise in resolving transaction problems between Binance Smart Chain and Coinbase, your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time and support!

Comment: Ethereum and BSC are different chains. You can't send assets from one to the other without a bridge.
When you say you sent it from coinbase, do you mean the coinbase wallet for which you have your own private key, or do you mean an exchange withdrawal?

If the transaction was successful check the destination address on the source chain. If it is pending it will still be at the source address, again on the source chain.

Do you want to share the hash and we can look at the situation?

Comment: Sure, [Here's the hash for the incoming USDT from BNB chain to my Coinbase Wallet](https://bscscan.com/tx/0x47d1e5a26ea95617ed7aa2cc89372774cc211b34f486478671e66d906d4d9d36)

Comment: This transaction was successful, but it looks like you being sent a scam token, since it isn't the binance supported binance pegged USDT, and the token has warnings about being untrustworthy. 
Seems the token being labeled a scam has confused into thinking it never arrived.

1000 of the scam token copy and paste contract from "Create your own token @ https://www.createmytoken.com", in your wallet.
https://bscscan.com/token/0x037499ebb453c6c84f1888c783ef8b75a257bd29?a=0xa56bd889a577aa4987c21396bcb8e1daa311320d

Comment: For completeness. Is important to note that anyone can create and deploy any token with any word in the name field. 
Do not use that as verification of a tokens source, legitimacy or available liquidity. 
Use the hash address and compare it with the token you know to be correct through its listing from the source deployments page, or its deep liquidity and availability on exchanges.

Answer (score -1):

First, you got a find the transaction hash or ID of the stuck one. Then, use that to fetch the transaction details. You can use Binance's API or some library for that.

Now comes the fun part! Adjust the gas price, mate! You want to make it higher than before to catch those miners' attention. They love the shiny coins, ya know! Calculate a good gas price, add it to the transaction, and you're golden.

Finally, **rebroadcast** the updated transaction using your wallet's API or some other tool you fancy. Don't forget to include the updated gas price and other deets.

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3('YOUR_PROVIDER_URL');

const transactionHash = 'YOUR_TRANSACTION_HASH';
const updatedGasPrice = web3.utils.toWei('100', 'gwei');

web3.eth.getTransaction(transactionHash)
  .then((transaction) => {
    transaction.gasPrice = updatedGasPrice;
    web3.eth.sendTransaction(transaction)
      .then((receipt) => {
        console.log('Transaction rebroadcasted:', receipt);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error rebroadcasting transaction:', error);
      });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error fetching transaction details:', error);
  });
```

Comment: Your solution involving direct interactions with the blockchain using Web3 and adjusting gas prices seems interesting, but it's important to clarify that Coinbase operates its own systems and manages the gas fees on behalf of its users. As a user, I don't have direct control over gas fees or low-level blockchain interactions when using Coinbase.

Comment: @TomCruise, tahnks for your clear answer.